# jQuery doesn't want to display the second attribute option

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm making a code that checks if the field has a value, and also verifies if the field has ONLY numbers.  It all works, but it doesn't want to display the placeholder, "That's not a number!"  Try typing in letters in the fiddle, you'll see!  The border changes color, but the placeholder does not.  I think it isn't working because it doesn't want to change the DOM element more than once?

Here's the jsFiddle :: http://jsfiddle.net/9Kb2Q/

Thanks for your time!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#btn").on("click", function(evt){

    var fldVal = $("#fld").val();

    if(fldVal == "" || fldVal == null){
        $("#fld").attr("placeholder","You left it blank, yo.");
        $("#fld").css("border-color", "#da8c8c");
        $("#fld").addClass('error-color');
        evt.preventDefault();
    } else if(isNaN(fldVal) == true){
        $("#fld").attr("placeholder","That's not a number!");
        $("#fld").css("border-color", "#da8c8c");
        $("#fld").addClass('error-color');
        evt.preventDefault();
    }

});

});
```

Comment: the placeholder will appear only if the input is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the value so that the placeholder can come

```
$("#fld").attr("placeholder","That's not a number!").val('');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/M75SW/)